# Static css in Django works unstable

Tags: python, html, css, django, pycharm

I have css with following content in ecommerce/ecommerce/static/css folder:

```
body {background: #68951c;}
h1 {color: #000000;}
```

When I want to change the color of the background, it changes in PyCharm, but it doesn't change on the web page even when I change the color in BOTH 1) e-commerce/static/css and 2) e-commerce/static/css manually.
Even though command "python manage.py collectstatic" had run and the server had re-run it is needlessly.
Only one effect - when I ctrl+X following string in html page:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
```

then the background evaporates. And when I insert the upper markup and refresh the page, it appears again

(upper markup contained in , in  it is not working for some reason)

[image: Project folders]

Comment: A typo (or three of them) in technical details is never irrelevant!

Comment: The spelling was incorrect only on the stackoverflow, it is obvious that it's correct in the project

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this simply is a caching problem. Try to hard reload your browser each time(or just have dev tools open)

Unless you have some more elaborate front-end build process (e.g. gulp, webpack etc.) In that case, you should rebuild or watch for file changes

Answer (score -1):

If a lot of css files, and then you write css to a new file and you want to go back to the previous file, you have to change the file name to make it work, for example first_file.css second_file.css if you want to go back to first_file.css you have to rename first_file. css becomes first_file_rename.css like this and then it works, I don't know what the problem is, I just got the easy alternative

Comment: There is no need to change the file names. I am guessing that caching in your browser must have been "the problem". Try disabling cache